# Warn vs. Caution

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences, synonyms

The verb "**[warn](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/warn)**" means "to make someone realize a possible danger or problem, especially one in the future", and the verb "**[caution](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/caution)**" means "*to warn* someone about a possible problem or danger".

Apparently, the verbs are synonyms, and more often than not they are interchangeable:

> They cautioned/warned her not to walk through the park at night.

However, there is some slight difference in the meaning which I feel but can't put into words. When are the verbs not interchangeable?

Comment: *cautioned her* feels more caring, *warned her* feels more like having a negative consequence attached to the action you're warning for. The latter could even be a threat (".. or else").

Comment: -1 No citations included

Comment: @user I've edited the question.

Comment: Thanks but nonetheless the question belongs on [English Language Leaners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Merriam-Webster, the word [**warning**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warning) has these meanings:

> **1** : the act of warning : the state of being warned · he had *warning* of his illness
>
> **2** : something that warns or serves to warn; *especially* : a notice or bulletin that alerts the public to an imminent hazard (such as a tornado, thunderstorm, or flood)

Meanwhile, the word [**caution**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caution) has these meanings:

> **1** : WARNING, ADMONISHMENT · Her comments were intended as a *caution* to us to protect our property.
>
> **2** : PRECAUTION · a surgeon taking the *caution* of sterilizing his instruments
>
> **3** : prudent forethought to minimize risk · Use *caution* when operating a chain saw.
>
> **4** : one that astonishes or commands attention · some shoes you see … these days are a *caution* —Esquire

As you can see, one sense of *warning* is the same as *caution*, but not all senses. In other words, they are only synonymous in specific uses.

For example, the use of *caution* by British police as mentioned in another answer would be used in the fourth sense of the definition (or possibly the third, depending on how I look at it)—not the first sense that is synonymous with *warning*.

---

When I use the two words, aside from the specific senses per the dictionary definition, I treat them as a matter of degree.

I think of a *caution* as related to something important but not urgent, whereas I think of a *warning* as something related to a more severe and immediate threat or danger.

> I was cautioned to not restart my computer while it was in the middle of an update.
> Use caution when crossing the street.
> She was cautioned to tell the truth in court.
>
> I warned her about the muggings in the park.
> I warned them to leave town because of the impending hurricane.
> Cigarettes come with a health warning.

And in different contexts the other word would be used:

> I was *warned* to not turn on my computer because of the bomb attached to it.
> We ware *warned* to not cross the street until the gas leak was fixed.
> They *cautioned* me to leave town because of the impending media event.
> You were *cautioned* to not smoke in a smoke-free zone.

Also, while I'm used to the expression *a word of warning*, I've never heard heard the expression *a word of caution*. So, the different words are used in different expressions and have different associations.

Answer (score 0):

At least in British English ["to caution someone"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_caution) is most common as a Police term just short of arrest. In general saying you **cautioned** someone rather than **warned** them would sound faintly old fashioned.

On notices Caution and Warning are probably equally common.